# Validity of Induction Proof - $\{ \land, \top, \bot \}$ is an incomplete set of connectives

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus

> I need to verify a proof of the fact that $\{ \land, \top, \bot  \}$
>   is not complete.

I consider $\top$ and $\bot$ to be $0$-ary logical connectives that are constantly true or false. That is for any truth assignment $v,$ the connective $ \bot $ operates on the empty set to return $v(\bot) = F$

**Proof:** Let $C$ be the set of formulas generated from the propositional variables by the above connectives. Let $S$ be set of formulas $\alpha$ such that for every truth assignment $v$ involving its propositional variables, $ \overline{v}(\alpha)= F $ if $ v(X) = F $ for at least one variable $X$ in $\alpha$.

All the propositional symbols are in $S$. Suppose $\alpha, \beta$ are arbitrary formulas in $S$. It can be seen that $ (\alpha \land \beta), (\alpha \land \bot) $ and $ (\alpha \land \top) $ are all in $S$. Hence by induction on complexity, $S = C$.

Hence no formula in $C$ can model $(\lnot A)$ for a propositional symbol $A$.

$\mathscr Q.E.D.$

> My issue is with the incorporation of $ \{ \top, \bot \}$ in the
>   induction process. Is my method correct? Or should I first say that
>   all the variables are in $S$. Then take $S' = S \cup \{ \top, \bot \}
>  $ and use the induction argument on $S'$. I think the text I use,
>   *Enderton*, fails to specify how these $0$-ary connectives act in the *generation process* of formulas. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See Enderton, page 50 : "Now an $n$-ary connective symbol combines with $n$ wffs to produce a new wff. When $n = 0$, we
have that $\bot$ is a wff all by itself. It differs from the sentence symbols in that $v(\bot) = F$ for every $v$; i.e., $\bot$ is a logical symbol always assigned the value F."

Comment: Thus, the inductive def of wff must be like : (i) every propositional symbols is a wff; (ii) $\top$ and $\bot$ are wffs; (iii) if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are wffs, then so is $(\alpha \land \beta)$. Case (iii) includes the possibility that $\alpha$ or $\beta$ are $\top$ or $\bot$.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: Thanks. Think I get it. One more query, will this proof work then? Is the statement " If $v(X) = F$ for at least one variable $X$ in $\alpha$ then $\overline{v}(\alpha)$" false for $\alpha \in \{\top, \bot\}$ or is it vacuously true?

Comment: "then $\overline v(\alpha)$ ..." what ? In general , "If $v(X)=F$ for at least one variable $X$ in $\alpha$, then ..." will be vacuously true for $\top, \bot$, due to the fact that there is **no** $X$ in them.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: Sorry I meant $\overline{v} (\alpha) = F$. Thanks a lot. Much appreciated.